# Deleting bot's response when the person who triggered the bot response deletes their initial message

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to make my discord bot say something when someone talks and if that person deletes their message the bot will delete it's response.

The Bot is for discord written in python using discord.py, trying to delete it's response when the person it is responding to deletes their message.

```py
BOT_PREFIX = '.', '?'
message_list = {}
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX, message_list={})


@bot.event
async def on_message_delete(message):
    if message in message_list:
        await message.channel.delete()
        del message_list[message]


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    print(message.author.id)
    if message.author.id == 137351212856115200:
        response = await message.channel.send('Message')
        message_list[message] = response
        await bot.process_commands(message)
    else:
        await bot.process_commands(message)
        return
```

I expect it to detect when the person deletes their message it will delete its response, but it is trying to delete the person's deleted message.

Comment: Should you be specifying which message to delete, rather than blindly calling delete on the channel?

Comment: @tehhowch I'm pretty new at python and am not sure how i would specify which message to delete.  If I try to do `await message.channel.delete(message_list)` it throws an error: `TypeError: delete() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given `

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Replaced `await message.channel.delete()` with `await message_list[message].delete()`